# CoffeeScript syntax highlighting not showing up in Sublime Text 2

Tags: coffeescript, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I needed to do some coding in CoffeeScript, so I found https://github.com/Xavura/CoffeeScript-Sublime-Plugin and I installed it using Package Control. I restarted Sublime Text and everything I type in my `.js.coffee` file is still plain white. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Open a `.coffee` file, then go to **`View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... -> CoffeeScript`**. Now, any time you open a CoffeeScript file it should have the correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: why havent they provided this instruction on the github page?